# Have hero video and div below 'bleed' into each other

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a hero video that is black and gold and a black dive underneath...

Click to see image

[image: 1]

I would like to blur the bottom border of the video and or the top border of the black div so that they appear to 'bleed into each other'.

I have tried everything I can think of / find on the interweb, so... filter: blur, mask-image, backdrop-filter: blur. but nothing seems to do the trick. 'filter: blur' got the closest but I don't want the entire video blurred, just the bottom border.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linear gradient on the div from black to transparent to create a fake "blur border" effect.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    position: relative;
}
.video {
    width: 100%;
}
.myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000 95%, rgba(0,0,0,0));
    height: 50vw;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <img class="video" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ktg0.png" alt="This is the video">
        <div class="myDiv"></div>
</header>
```